# Android TV Chromecast Receiver apps that can intercept Netflix as a sender app

Tags: chromecast, android-tv, netflix

I developed an Android TV receiver app that manages to intercept the call of another Android sender app also developed by me on the Android TV Chromecast box device.
That’s why I developed a sender app that transmits on the ID , of my Android TV receiver app, registered on the chromecast console.
If I try to use Netflix as a sender app, it doesn’t work because my receiving app doesn’t see the call from the sending Netflix app.
So would it be possible to develop an Android TV receiver app that intercepts the connection intention (as soon as you select the box after pressing the chromecast symbol rectangle) from Netflix?

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you very much to all of you